# Retrieve spark dataframe array column value and reuse it as a column name in a UDF

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

I am trying to get the column name from one column and pass it as a parameter to udf. for eg.
I have a DataFrame:

```
 | name   | array_column       | column4 | column5 |
 |--------|--------------------|---------|---------|
 | first  | column4,column5    |   V1    |    V2   |
 | test   | column4,column5    |   V1    |    V2   |
 | choose | column3,column5    |   V1    |    V2   |

df.withcolumn("test",udf(array_column(0),arraycolumn(1)))
```

where `array_column(0)` and `array_column(1)` which are `column4` and `column5` respectively represents 2 column names in the dataframe.

I want to bascially do udf(column4,column5) but i need to get array_column values and pass them as a paramter of my udf

I tried setting it, but for some reason the column is not called properly. It is called as `String` instead of the elements of the array

Comment: What do you mean by calculate another column ? What is your exact requirement ? Could you add the code that doesn't work ? thanks

Comment: My requirement is basically to calculcate some metrics. My dataframe already has the following columns for eg. col1,col2,col3,col4,metricscol . The metrics col will have for eg "col2,col3" . I have to use the metriccol to identify which col i need to use to calculate my metrics. I have to take the array in metric col and use it like dataframe.select(metriccol(0)) which should give me values in dataframe.col2

Comment: Dataframe($"MetricsCol"(0))) should behave as Dataframe("column2") in the comment example

Comment: sorry I am trying to understand your issue, but it's not clear for me. could you edit your question, and make the difference between column names, the values in the column and the expected result. thanks

Comment: What I understand is: you have a dataframe, that contains 5 columns: `col1, col2, col3, col4` and `metrics`.
`metrics` is of type array of size 2, and has as value `[col4, col5]`.

Comment: can you check the question now. i have edited it. The question is i need to get values from a column in dataframe. These values are actual column names present in the dataframe. I then want to use these values to pass as column names to the udf.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202055/discussion-between-driss-nejjar-and-vignesh-asokan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code:

Start by creating 2 case classes to manipulate your dataframes:

```scala
case class ResultArray(metric1: Double, metric2: Double, metric3: Double, metric4: Double, metricName: String, opportunityMetricsCol: Array[String])

case class ExpectedResult(value: String)
```

Then, you can extract the expected columns as the following:

```scala
val resultArray = Seq(ResultArray(0.55, 0.66012, 164.8204, 4.5,"MetricCalc1", Array("metric1","metric2")),
      ResultArray(0.55, 0.66012, 164.8204, 4.5,"MetricCalc1", Array("metric3","metric4")))

+-------+-------+--------+-------+-----------+---------------------+
|metric1|metric2|metric3 |metric4|metricName |opportunityMetricsCol|
+-------+-------+--------+-------+-----------+---------------------+
|0.55   |0.66012|164.8204|4.5    |MetricCalc1|[metric1, metric2]   |
|0.55   |0.66012|164.8204|4.5    |MetricCalc1|[metric3, metric4]   |
+-------+-------+--------+-------+-----------+---------------------+

    val resultArrayDF = resultArray.toDF

    val expectedResult: Dataset[ExpectedResult] = resultArrayDF.map{ value =>
      val opportunityMetricsCol: util.List[String] = value.getList(5)

      ExpectedResult(opportunityMetricsCol.get(0))

    }

    resultArrayDF.select(expectedResult.first().value).show(false)

    expectedResult.show(false)

+-------+
|metric1|
+-------+
|0.55   |
|0.55   |
+-------+
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi Driss. I hav tried this. but i keep getting issues when i try to do df.select. PFB the code i am using.
    `scala> val expectedResult: Dataset[ExpectedResult] = outputFinalDf.map{ value => 
     val opportunityMetricsCol: java.util.List[String] = value.getList(5)
     | ExpectedResult(opportunityMetricsCol.get(0))}
      expectedResult: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[ExpectedResult] = [value: string]

scala> outputFinalDf.select(expectedResult.first().value).show(false)  `

what is value in expected result set.?

Comment: The value expected is the content of metric1 column

Comment: It is saying cannot convert a string to a seq.
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to scala.collection.Seq

Comment: Could you update your question, by adding the used code and the stacktrace please ?

Comment: Where do you have the error ? At which step of your code ?

Comment: Here 
outputFinalDf.select(expectedResult.first().value).show(false)

Comment: So may be we can split this one into many objects, you can assign expectedResult.first().value to a val. And then, do the select in another assignment